# Change text when link clicked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to change the button to read `Close` when clicked and also to act as a Close too.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cxggpygx/)**

How do I achieve this with my current code?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Expand Panel
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");   
    });     

    // Switch visiblility of the "Close Panel" button
    $("#close").click(function () {
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.is(':visible')` to check whether div is visible and set text appropriately.

*code*

```
$("#open").click(function () {
    $("div#panel").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        if ($("div#panel").is(':visible')) {
            $("#open").text('Close');
        } else {
            $("#open").text('Quick Quote');
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0u3f953j/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this using `.slideToggle()`:

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    if($("div#panel").is(':visible'))
         $(this).html('Quick Quote');
    else 
         $(this).html('Close Quote');
    $("div#panel").slideToggle("slow"); 
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1jp0bh9n/)**

Comment: Slide effect is perfect - how do I also change the text to 'Close'?

Answer (score 0):

Using SlideToggle is a neat solution.

You can also achieve the functionality using addClass and removeClass. Without making much changes to the code that you have written.

http://jsfiddle.net/4dkoke6w/

I have created a class "hidden" and it applies "display: none" styling.

```
// Expand Panel
$("#open").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");   
    $("#open").addClass("hidden");
     $("#close").removeClass("hidden");
});     

// Switch visiblility of the "Close Panel" button
$("#close").click(function () {
    $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
    $("#close").addClass("hidden");
    $("#open").removeClass("hidden");
});
```